# Diifferetn result in Linux and Visual Studio

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-2015

Does anybody know why compiling program in Visual Studio 2015 gives different result (those are correct I want to keep them) vs Linux Ubuntu (those are wrong).?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main() {
    int i,j,k;
    int pair = 0;
    char array1[][12] = { "strike", "march", "play", "cool", "may", "july", 
                            "school", "bad", "good", "linux", "really" , "weird"};
    char word[12];
    char array2[][12] = {  "really", "mount", "hike", "bad", "linux", "weird","define"};
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            if (strcmp(array1[i], array2[j])==0) {
                strcpy(word, array1[i]);
                for (k = 0; word[k]!='\0'; k++) {
                    word[k] = toupper(word[k]);
                }
                printf("%s\n", word);
                pair++;
            }           
        }       
    }
    printf("\nTotal pairs: %d", pair);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Note, in your windows terminal, you can click the window property control in the top-left and choose `Edit->Mark` which will then allow you to select the text in the window to copy as text. Pressing `[Enter]` then copies the text which you can paste into your question here (indented by *4-spaces*) instead of posting screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading beyond the end of an array invokes *undefined behavior* in C. Once your program invokes *undefined behavior* anything can happen or nothing at all. It is simply undefined. As aneesh correctly notes, the reason is due to iterating over `12` elements in `array2` where ony `7` exist. This exposes one of the primary reasons filling your code with "*magic numbers*" (like `12`) is a bad idea.

Instead, what you want to do is properly define *constants* for any specified quantity (such as your maximum number of characters in each string in `array1` and `array2`) and then compute the value of any remaining quantities not previously defined.

The `sizeof` operator provides you with the method to determine the number of elements present in `array1` and `array2`. For example:

```
a1elem = sizeof array1 / sizeof *array1;  /* get number of    */
a2elem = sizeof array2 / sizeof *array2;  /* elements in each */

for (i = 0; i < a1elem; i++) {      /* loop over valid range  */
    for (j = 0; j < a2elem; j++) {  /* for array1 & array2    */
```

(***note:*** the `sizeof` operator can only be used to determine the `sizeof` an **array where the declaration is visible within the present scope**) For example, if you pass an array to a function you **cannot** use `sizeof` to determine the array size within the function.

Putting the pieces together, you could do something like the following and have it work correctly regardless of the operating system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum { MAXL = 12 };

int main (void) {
    int a1elem, a2elem, i, j, k, pair = 0;
    char array1[][MAXL] = { "strike", "march", "play", "cool", 
                            "may", "july", "school", "bad", 
                            "good", "linux", "really" , "weird"},
         array2[][MAXL] = { "really", "mount", "hike", 
                            "bad", "linux", "weird","define"},
         word[MAXL] = "";

    a1elem = sizeof array1 / sizeof *array1;  /* get number of    */
    a2elem = sizeof array2 / sizeof *array2;  /* elements in each */

    for (i = 0; i < a1elem; i++)         /* loop over valid range */
        for (j = 0; j < a2elem; j++)     /* for array1 & array2   */
            if (strcmp (array1[i], array2[j])==0) {
                strcpy (word, array1[i]);
                for (k = 0; word[k]; k++)
                    word[k] = toupper (word[k]);
                printf ("%s\n", word);
                pair++;
            }           

    printf ("\nTotal pairs: %d\n", pair);
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    getchar();
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ uname -snrmo
Linux valkyrie 4.7.4-1-ARCH x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ./bin/arraysz
BAD
LINUX
REALLY
WEIRD

Total pairs: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In the array2[], you have only 7 elements. And your loop count is 12. That means you are over indexing array2[]. This will cause your program to behave in undefined manner in different platforms.